# Sprite movement only works the first time, can't figure out why

Tags: java, libgdx, movement, input

In my libGDX game I have finally managed to get the sprite to move the way I want him to but for some reason my desired outcome only works the first time I run the code. If I try to run it again, he immediately flies off the screen. If I then comment out one of the brackets, save and then put it back in and run a test, he moves as I want him to (but only the first time). Am I missing something?

***EDIT***: Ok I changed the code and now I have a new problem, he moves but not smoothly like he does when I move him with the keyboard. now he sort of teleports forwards or backwards about 5pixels every time the screen is clicked (or touched).

Partial Player class:

```
public class Player extends Entity implements InputProcessor{

OrthographicCamera camera;
Rectangle rectangle;
Vector3 touchPos;

public Player(Vector2 pos, Vector2 direction) {
    super(TextureManager.PLAYER, pos, direction);
    rectangle = new Rectangle(); //for hitbox
    }

@Override
public void update() {

    camera = new OrthographicCamera(240, 400);
    camera.position.set(240 / 2, 400 / 2, 0);
    rectangle.set(pos.x, pos.y + 40, 32, 22); //hitbox
    touchPos = new Vector3();

    pos.add(direction);{

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);


    //the keyboard inputs below work exactly how I want them to     
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A)) // left
        setDirection(-300, 0);
    else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D)) // right
        setDirection(300, 0);
    else
        setDirection(0, 0);         
    }

    // make sure player stays inside stage
    if (pos.x < 0) pos.x = 0;
    else if (pos.x > 240 - 32) pos.x = 240 - 32;

}

public void moveLeft() {
    setDirection(-300, 0);
}

public void moveRight() {
    setDirection(300, 0);
}

public void Still() {
    setDirection(0, 0);
}


@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (screenX < ManicMeltdowns.WIDTH / 2 && screenY > ManicMeltdowns.HEIGHT / 2){
        moveLeft();
    }

    if (screenX > ManicMeltdowns.WIDTH / 2 && screenY > ManicMeltdowns.HEIGHT / 2){
        moveRight();
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (screenX < ManicMeltdowns.WIDTH / 2 && screenY > ManicMeltdowns.HEIGHT / 2){
        Still();
    }

    if (screenX > ManicMeltdowns.WIDTH / 2 && screenY > ManicMeltdowns.HEIGHT / 2){
        Still();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: [These 2 brackets match](http://i.stack.imgur.com/w7pnn.png), which seems like a strange thing to do. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Anko Yeah you are right it's weird but when I take `if (pos.x < 0) pos.x = 0` etc out of `pos.add(direction)` the player immediately flies out of the screen...

Comment: Not sure, cause you're doing very weird java stuff here, but aren't your brackets defining a kind of method initialization block, that would explain why the code is executed only once ? (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

Comment: @Anko I edited the code a bit and took the bracket out but now there's a new problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the `else` condition after you check the A and D keys, since if no key is pressed it will reset the direction to 0, 0 every time the `update()` method is called. Instead of calling `moveLeft()` and `moveRight()` in the `touchDown` and `touchUp` you should keep track of each pointer passed by the `touchDown` and `touchUp` methods and check whether the pointers are in the zones for a left or right movement in the `update()` method.

For example, create a class Pointer:

```
public class Pointer {
    public int x = 0, y = 0;
    public boolean down = false;
}
```

Then, create an array of pointers, `touches[]`, in either the game class or the `Player` class to keep track of the touches. The length of `touches[]` should be however many touches you plan on recognizing, I usually use 10 just as a safe maximum. It would be best to put your array in the class that is the `InputProcessor`, which seems to be your `Player` class although it is typically the game class. Your `touchDown`, `touchDragged` and `touchUp` methods would change the values of `x`, `y`, and `down` for the `Pointer` at its index in `touches[]`. Then in `update()` iterate through the array and check for each touch.

For example:

```
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    if (pointer < touches.length){
        touches[pointer].x = screenX;
        touches[pointer].y = screenY;
        touches[pointer].down = true;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    if (pointer < touches.length){
        touches[pointer].x = screenX;
        touches[pointer].y = screenY;
        touches[pointer].down = false;
        return true;
    }
    return false;

@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    if (pointer < touches.length){
        touches[pointer].x = screenX;
        touches[pointer].y = screenY;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Side Notes: It seems like your `update()` method would only work with a fixed framerate, which may make movement speeds different on different devices unless a fixed framerate loop is implemented elsewhere in the code. In addition, you may want to move `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this)` to the constructor of the Player class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How exactly would I go about keeping track of each pointer as you say? I'm not even sure what you mean to be honest.

Comment: @Harry I updated the answer with my suggestion.

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry if this is a stupid question but do I create the array `touches[]` in the Pointer class...?

Comment: Not at all @Harry . I updated the answer to cover where the creation of `touches[]` should be. It seems strange to me that your `Player` class implements `InputProcessor` instead of whatever game class you're using, I would personally pass a reference to the game class in the constructor of `Player` and then use that reference to access `touches[]` while the game class instead implements `InputProcessor`.

Comment: thanks again for your help, I'm still trying to do it how you said but I'm struggling a bit, in the meantime I was wondering about what you said originally about the else condition causing the problem. How come it wasn't causing the same problem for the keyboard input? Keyboard input works exactly how I want it to and I still don't understand why it messes up when touch is implemented?

Comment: @Harry , the `touchDown` method is called when the user presses the screen. When that occurs, you set the direction to the left or right. This happens once per touch. When `update` is called, you check if a key is pressed, and set the direction corresponding to the key. However, if no key is pressed, you reset the direction to 0, 0, even if the finger is still on the screen. Since no keys are being pressed when the finger is on the touchscreen, `update` resets the direction to zero. The player still moves a little bit after a touch since you call `pos.add(direction)` before checking the keys.